# Freemarker replacing JSPs?

Tags: templates, jsp, view, freemarker

I am new to Freemarker and learning more about it.

I'm coming from JSP background and so far I've used the same for VIEW layer in all my application.

I might sound naive, but it's hard for me to think of building a web application without JSP.

I'm curious to know If someone has used Freemarker completely in their application for VIEW layer (i.e. not even a single JSP at all)?

Using Freemarker is as smooth as JSP for building VIEWs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarker is a perfectly viable alternative to JSP. I've successfully used it in many web applications, and I've found it enforces a better separation of concerns between the view and the other layers.

One major difference is that FreeMarker templates don't support embedded Java code and are not limited to the Servlet paradigm.

The Spring framework provides everything you need to use FreeMarker instead of JSP.